# Go foreground when DownloadManager notification clicked

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have a long lasting download using Android's native [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) API. I've registered the broadcast receivers at my AndroidManifest.xml like:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".services.DownloadNotificationClickedReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now I wonder: how, at `DownloadNotificationClickedReceiver`class, would I request my application to go foreground (only) if it was put in background by the user and how to specify the activity it should go (my downloads activity).

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by foreground and background

Comment: @RohitSingh I mean background when it gets minimized and foreground when it is visible to user.